# How to create a single page with a jump select menu?

Tags: 7

I need to create a page with a single jump select menu. Once the user makes a selection he/she will be redirected to a **view page** where the selection will be used as **contextual filter**

Can I do it with the webform module? What other option do I have?

I've found this one: http://drupal.org/project/jump but just a dev version for d7.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views provides a "jump menu" display, you could just use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a page with a page callback using [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7). Here is a workaround.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['mypage'] = array(
        'title' => 'Available vouchers for you',
        'page callback' => 'mymodule_country_select_page',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
    ); 
    return $items;
} 

function mymodule_country_select_page(){
    $country = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#name' => 'country',
        '#title' => t('Select country to see your available Vouchers'),
        '#options' => array(
            '' => t(' - Select - ')
        ),
        '#attributes' => array(
            'onchange' => "window.location=this.value"
        ),
    );

    $options = array(
        '1' => 'Country 1',
        '2' => 'Country 2',
        '3' => 'Country 3',
    );  
    foreach($options as $arg => $name){
        $url = url('path/to/view/', array('query'=> array('arg'=>$arg), 'absolute'=>TRUE));
        $country['#options'][$url] = t($name);
    }

    return render($country);
}
```